# Modularized def for upgrade Label text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, module

I am starting to program graphical interfaces in Python by modularizing a command (`def`) that is pressed by pressing a **`Button`** and the **`Label`** text is updated through a **`def`** that is in **`__init__.py`**. But, the program always starts with the modified text as if the button had already been clicked.
I am a beginner and I did not find any similar problem in this forum and I would like to know what must be done for this to be solved. Details follow below.

[image]

> **`main.py`**

```py
from tkinter import *

from upgrader import upgrade

root = Tk()
root.title('Test')

poster = Label(root, text='Old Text')
poster.grid(row=0, column=0)

botao = Button(root, text='Change', command=upgrade(poster))
botao.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

> **`__init__.py`** from upgrader

```py
def upgrade(t):
    u = t['text'] = 'New Text'
    return u
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command=upgrade(poster)` will execute `upgrade(poster)` immediately when creating the button `botao`.

Use `command=lambda: upgrade(poster)` instead.

Comment: What if it's an image? Should I create a variable to return itself? What do you recommend to me? Is it something like: ```def upgrade(img): u = poster['image'] = PhotoImage(file='image.png'); return u``` ?

Comment: Try something like: `def upgrade(poster): poster.image = PhotoImage(file='image.png'); poster['image'] = poster.image`.  Note that the first line is to save a reference of the image in order to avoid the image from being garbage collected.